# Upload file to Firebase Storage using AngularFire2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am working on a project with Angular2 and Firebase and I am willing to upload images to Firebase Storage.

So, I created the Component with the contructor and the function, and, then, the template. I am not sure whether the way I declare the variable firebaseApp,   `public firebaseApp: FirebaseApp;` is correct.

So, in my component, I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA, MdButton } from '@angular/material';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
import 'firebase/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'individual-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})

export class IndividualChat implements OnInit {
    public firebaseApp: FirebaseApp;
constructor(
    firebaseApp: FirebaseApp,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
    public af: AngularFireDatabase,
    public http: Http,
    public dialog: MdDialog
  ){ }

   EditChatData(){
      this.af.object('groupConversations/'+ this.my_id + '/' +this.conversation_id ).update({ groupName: this.group_edit_data.name ? this.group_edit_data.name : 'New Group' });        

  }
    onChange(files) {
    console.log(files, files[0]);
      let storageRef = this.firebaseApp.storage().ref().child('groupImages');

      storageRef.put(files[0]).then( snapshot => {
        console.log('successfully added');        
      }).catch(err => { console.error("Whoupsss!", err) })
    }
  ...
}
```

And the form I created in my template looks like this:

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="EditChatData()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" #file (change)="onChange(file.files)" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Group name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="group_edit_data.name" #name="ngModel" class="form-control" value=" {{ group_name }}" />
  <button class="btn">DONE</button>
</form>
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'storage' of undefined
```

And, the console.log in my onChange(files) return this object:

```
FileList {0: File, length: 1}
length: 1,
0: File {
lastModified: 1503324156295
lastModifiedDate: Mon Aug 21 2017 17:02:36 GMT+0300 (EEST),
name:"Screenshot from 2017-08-21 17-02-36.png",
size: 401442,
type: "image/png",
webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'storage' of undefined` tells you that `this.firebaseApp` is `undefined`.

You can initialize it in the constructor, this way:

```
constructor(
  firebaseApp: FirebaseApp,
  public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
  public af: AngularFireDatabase,
  public http: Http,
  public dialog: MdDialog
) {
  this.firebaseApp = firebaseApp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since FirebaseApp is a service you need to inject in the constructor.Only the variables has to be declared above constructor.Make sure you import FirebaseApp.